# Pushing localStorage data from javascript based todo-list to mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, list, local-storage

So, I've created a basic todo list app using javascript and relatively basic css and html files. I am currently storing each todo list item in the localstorage but I want to push the local storage data to a mysql database. I've created a simple schema and database connection js file, **but I am having issues figuring out the best way to essentially push the localstorage data into mysql**. I attempted going the POST & GET method and using API routes but I feel like that is overcomplicating what I am trying to do.

Code for storing data in localstorage:

```
//Currently storing todo list data in local storage
var data = (localStorage.getItem('todoList')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList')):{
  todo: [],
  completed: []
};

function dataObjectUpdated() {
    localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Current database connection js:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 3306,

  // Your username
  user: "root",

  // Your password
  password: "",
  database: "todo_list"
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("connected as id " + connection.threadId);
  connection.end();
});
```

Basic schema:

```
-- Drops the todo_list if it exists currently --
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS todo_list;
-- Creates the "todo_list" database --
CREATE DATABASE todo_list;

-- Makes it so all of the following code will affect todo_list --
USE todo_list;

-- Creates the table "favorite_foods" within todo_list --
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  -- Makes a string column called "Task" which cannot contain null --
  Task VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

main.js file for reference:

```
    //Currently storing todo list data in local storage
var data = (localStorage.getItem('todoList')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList')):{
  todo: [],
  completed: []
};


//Remove and completed svg code icons

var removeSVG = '<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22 22;" xml:space="preserve"><g><g><path class="fill" d="M16.1,3.6h-1.9V3.3c0-1.3-1-2.3-2.3-2.3h-1.7C8.9,1,7.8,2,7.8,3.3v0.2H5.9c-1.3,0-2.3,1-2.3,2.3v1.3c0,0.5,0.4,0.9,0.9,1v10.5c0,1.3,1,2.3,2.3,2.3h8.5c1.3,0,2.3-1,2.3-2.3V8.2c0.5-0.1,0.9-0.5,0.9-1V5.9C18.4,4.6,17.4,3.6,16.1,3.6z M9.1,3.3c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1h1.7c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1v0.2H9.1V3.3z M16.3,18.7c0,0.6-0.5,1.1-1.1,1.1H6.7c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1V8.2h10.6L16.3,18.7L16.3,18.7z M17.2,7H4.8V5.9c0-0.6,0.5-1.1,1.1-1.1h10.2c0.6,0,1.1,0.5,1.1,1.1V7z"/></g><g><g><path class="fill" d="M11,18c-0.4,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-6.8c0-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6s0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6v6.8C11.6,17.7,11.4,18,11,18z"/></g><g><path class="fill" d="M8,18c-0.4,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-6.8C7.4,10.2,7.7,10,8,10c0.4,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6v6.8C8.7,17.7,8.4,18,8,18z"/></g><g><path class="fill" d="M14,18c-0.4,0-0.6-0.3-0.6-0.6v-6.8c0-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.6c0.4,0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.6v6.8C14.6,17.7,14.3,18,14,18z"/></g></g></g></svg>'
var completeSVG = '<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22 22" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22 22;" xml:space="preserve"><rect y="0" class="noFill" width="22" height="22"/><g><path class="fill" d="M9.7,14.4L9.7,14.4c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.2l-2.7-2.7c-0.3-0.3-0.3-0.8,0-1.1s0.8-0.3,1.1,0l2.1,2.1l4.8-4.8c0.3-0.3,0.8-0.3,1.1,0s0.3,0.8,0,1.1l-5.3,5.3C10.1,14.3,9.9,14.4,9.7,14.4z"/></g></svg>'

renderTodoList();

//User clicking add button, if text is present in the task field, add task to the todo list
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var value = document.getElementById('task').value;
    if (value) {

        addItemToDOM(value);
        document.getElementById('task').value = '';

        data.todo.push(value);
        dataObjectUpdated();
    }

});

function addItem (value) {
  addItemToDOM(value);
  document.getElementById('item').value = '';

  data.todo.push(value);
  dataObjectUpdated();
}

function renderTodoList() {
  if (!data.todo.length && !data.completed.length) return;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.todo.length; i++) {
    var value = data.todo[i];
    addItemToDOM(value);
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < data.completed.length; j++) {
    var value = data.completed[j];
    addItemToDOM(value, true);
  }
}

function dataObjectUpdated() {
    localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(data));
}
//Remove item from the todo list function
function removeItem(){

  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var parent = item.parentNode;
  var id = parent.id;
  var value = item.innerText;

  if (id === 'todo') {
    data.todo.splice(data.todo.indexOf(value), 1);
  } else {
    data.completed.splice(data.completed.indexOf(value), 1);
  }


  dataObjectUpdated();
  parent.removeChild(item);
}
//Function for completed todo list items 
function completeItem() {
  var item = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var parent = item.parentNode;
  var id = parent.id;
  var value = item.innerText;

    if (id === 'todo') {
    data.todo.splice(data.todo.indexOf(value), 1);
    data.completed.push(value);
  } else {
    data.completed.splice(data.completed.indexOf(value), 1);
    data.todo.push(value);
  }
 dataObjectUpdated();
//
  var target = (id === 'todo') ? document.getElementById('completed'):document.getElementById('todo');

  parent.removeChild(item);
  target.insertBefore(item, target.childNodes[0]);

  }

//Adding a new todo task to the list
function addItemToDOM(task, completed){

    var list = (completed) ? document.getElementById('completed'):document.getElementById('todo');

    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = task;

    var buttons = document.createElement('div');
    buttons.classList.add('buttons');

    var remove = document.createElement('button');
    remove.classList.add('remove');
    remove.innerHTML = removeSVG;

//Add click event for removing task
    remove.addEventListener('click', removeItem);

    var complete = document.createElement('button');
    complete.classList.add('complete');
    complete.innerHTML = completeSVG;

//Add Click event for completing tasks
    complete.addEventListener('click', completeItem);




    buttons.appendChild(remove);
    buttons.appendChild(complete);
    item.appendChild(buttons);

    list.insertBefore(item, list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

I've done an npm install for express,node,mysql, and sequelize. To be very honest, **I really just need to store the todo items in a sql database and have them be persistent. I am only going the localstorage to sql route because I have not been able to figure out how to store the todo list items directly in a sql database.** Please let me know where I can clarify my issue if need be. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to write some SQL to actually insert the data into your todo list table. I believe that's really all you're missing.

Comment: I see. I'm having trouble figuring out where I would place the SQL code to insert the data into my todo list table and how I would trigger the table creation in the first place. Essentially, does the todo.sql actually need to be a portion of code inside a php file that establishes a connection and incorporates ajax to push the data to sql or would I insert ajax code in the main.js file? I'm basically having difficulty on where to place everything.

Comment: Your NPM package MYSQL has an example on how to perform queries with the package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries You should be able to find the operation you're looking for there. I would modify your connection.js file to handle both opening the connection and making a query.